# Unable to map Master Page Gallery to Windows XP

Tags: 2013, design, windows-xp

I've tried to map the master page gallery to my computer as a network drive. I've tried using the Tools > Map Network Drive method as well as `net use x: \server\folder\`. Both methods result in failure. I am on Windows XP SP3. I used a colleague's computer who has Windows 7. Using my username and the same methods, I was able to map the master page gallery to his computer.

Has anyone heard of an issue in not being able to map a master page gallery to a machine running XP?

Answer (score 0):

Keith,

Seems like Windows XP problem, nothing about SharePoint.. but following links may help you:
[New drive or mapped network drive not available in Windows Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297694)
[You receive an error message when try to map a network drive from a Windows XP workstation: "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957009)

PS: Why you using Windows XP, its old.. try switching to at least Windows 7 :)

Comment: Would love to upgrade right now but it isn't being rolled out to the company until early 2014.

I'm able to map drives from my SP 2010 sites no problem using the same methods.